# Calling action sheet from tabbaritem in tabbar app

Tags: ios, action, tabbar

**The idea.**

I'm developing a TabBarController based app.

There are the following 3 TabBarItems:

- Home (shows homeView within a navigation controller)
- Content (shows contentView within a navigation controller)
- Share (doesn't do what it's used to)

I'd like the TabBarItem "Share" to show an Action Sheet at the current view, not to change the view.

**What I've done.**

With the following lines I'm able to get the "Share"-TabBarItem Click/Touch.

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Share"]) {
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share this App" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancle" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Share on FaceBook", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

**The problem.**

Every time I select "Share", a blank view is shown.

How can I stop the TabBarItem from loading its view, just causing the Action Sheet being shown?

Greets and thank you for thinking about my problem!

@Christopher A: thanks for your response.

Placed the following code in my "projectAppDelegate.m" but the method isn't called when selecting a tabbaritem.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if ([viewController.title isEqualToString:@"Share"]) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

`tabBarController: shouldSelectViewController:` should allow you to programmatically set this.
Check out the details of it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ashouldSelectViewController%3a).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are showing sheet in `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`.

Try this one:

```
[sheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: still showing up the view in the background
EDIT: the wrong view ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use   [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow to show action.

Replace it with :

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

If you are not getting your tabBarController references then first get the reference of your UItabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController *)viewController
{
//    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = nil;
switch (tabBarController.selectedIndex) {
    case 1:
    {
        NSLog(@"item 1");
        UIActionSheet *shareAS = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:nil
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"shareToXX", @"shareToYY",nil];
        shareAS.actionSheetStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        shareAS.tag = 1;
        [shareAS showInView:self.window];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        NSLog(@"item 2");
       UIActionSheet *myAS = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:nil
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"AAA", @"BBB",@"CCC",@"DDD",nil];
        myAS.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        myAS.tag = 2;
        [myAS showInView:self.window];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

hope to help you.